# Animation of Logical and Mathematical Proofs

Tags: beamer, animations, mathematics, logicproof

I have 2 questions regarding animations of mathematical proofs:

1. I know that one can create a presentation using the Beamer package. I would also like to use animations. Is there an option to present the presentation like a PowerPoint presentation or is the option to export the file as pdf and then every animation produces another page? I am going to present mathematical proof, and if I'll have 50 pages of proof I reckon this could get up to 2000 pages in pdf if I use animation and that would probably burden the computer and not be so easy to get around the file.
2. I want to write proofs in Natural Deduction and I was delighted to find that there is [a package](https://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/nd/) to write them with. I would like to present the proof I write in my courses and hence use the beamer package and incorporate animation. I saw that there are animations in Beamer. I read about the \pause command. I was wondering if there a more sophisticated way to control the animation. For instance - when I start a new frame I would like show first my last proposition of the proof, so the students know what our aim is. Meaning, the last item on the page suppose to appear with a click, afterwards I would like to show the first proposition. I would also like to differentiate between the proposition and it's justification, and for them not to show up together (It gives the student a chance to think a bit for themselves about the justification). If this is not optional as a built-in function how would one program such a thing? What do I need to read about programming in Tex?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. This can all be done. Read up on `\onslide` and `\only` in the beamer manual. But yes, PDF presentations work by creating pages per effect which is way more portable than PowerPoint's effects. And I never had problems opening PDF of 2000 pages.